# How to bind to nested properties (generated from JSON) in Xamarin MVVM

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, mvvm, binding

I need some advice regarding binding to nested properties in generated class from JSON using Json2C#. So I'm using firebase cloud functions and I get a returned json string. I used that string to generate the below classes.

```
public class BusinessReturnedModel
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Longitude
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Line2
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Postcode
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Line1
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class County
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fields
    {
        public Line2 line_2 { get; set; }
        public City city { get; set; }
        public Postcode postcode { get; set; }
        public Line1 line_1 { get; set; }
        public County county { get; set; }
        public Country country { get; set; }
    }

    public class MapValue
    {
        public Fields fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public MapValue mapValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProfilePicture
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class BusinessType
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geohash
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Latitude
    {
        public string stringValue { get; set; }
        public string valueType { get; set; }
    }

    public class FieldsProto
    {
        public Longitude longitude { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; }
        public Name name { get; set; }
        public ProfilePicture profile_picture { get; set; }
        public BusinessType business_type { get; set; }
        public Geohash geohash { get; set; }
        public Latitude latitude { get; set; }
    }

    public class Settings
    {
        public string projectId { get; set; }
        public string firebaseVersion { get; set; }
        public string libName { get; set; }
        public string libVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public class Serializer
    {
        public bool allowUndefined { get; set; }
    }

    public class BackoffSettings
    {
        public int initialDelayMs { get; set; }
        public int maxDelayMs { get; set; }
        public double backoffFactor { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActiveClients
    {
    }

    public class FailedClients
    {
    }

    public class Promise
    {
    }

    public class TerminateDeferred
    {
        public Promise promise { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientPool
    {
        public int concurrentOperationLimit { get; set; }
        public int maxIdleClients { get; set; }
        public ActiveClients activeClients { get; set; }
        public FailedClients failedClients { get; set; }
        public bool terminated { get; set; }
        public TerminateDeferred terminateDeferred { get; set; }
    }

    public class Firestore
    {
        public Settings _settings { get; set; }
        public bool _settingsFrozen { get; set; }
        public Serializer _serializer { get; set; }
        public string _projectId { get; set; }
        public int registeredListenersCount { get; set; }
        public int bulkWritersCount { get; set; }
        public BackoffSettings _backoffSettings { get; set; }
        public ClientPool _clientPool { get; set; }
    }

    public class Path
    {
        public List<string> segments { get; set; }
        public string projectId { get; set; }
        public string databaseId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Converter
    {
    }

    public class Ref
    {
        public Firestore _firestore { get; set; }
        public Path _path { get; set; }
        public Converter _converter { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReadTime
    {
        public int _seconds { get; set; }
        public int _nanoseconds { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreateTime
    {
        public int _seconds { get; set; }
        public int _nanoseconds { get; set; }
    }

    public class UpdateTime
    {
        public int _seconds { get; set; }
        public int _nanoseconds { get; set; }
    }

    public class BusinessItem
    {
        public FieldsProto _fieldsProto { get; set; }
        public Ref _ref { get; set; }
        public Serializer _serializer { get; set; }
        public ReadTime _readTime { get; set; }
        public CreateTime _createTime { get; set; }
        public UpdateTime _updateTime { get; set; }
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public BusinessReturnedModel record;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a binding to these properties, below is my XAML.

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout>

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Businesses}"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="businessReturned:BusinessReturnedModel">
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                           Source="{Binding what goes here!!!???}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding}" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding}"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
                    
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

And below is my View Model SearchViewModel (well the parts that are relevant anyway..)

```
    public ICommand GetNearbyServicesCommand => new Command<List<BusinessItem>>(async (List<BusinessItem> businesses) => { BusinessList = await GetNearbyAsync(); });
    public ObservableCollection<BusinessItem> Businesses { get; set; }

    private List<BusinessItem> _businessList;
    public List<BusinessItem> BusinessList
    {
        get
        {
            return _businessList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_businessList != value)
            {
                _businessList = value;
                Businesses = new ObservableCollection<BusinessItem>(value);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

...//public async Task<List<BusinessItem>> GetNearbyAsync()
//Here is the after http client get etc..
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BusinessItem>>(content);

            Console.WriteLine(myDeserializedClass);

            return myDeserializedClass;

        }
//...
```

So the issue is that when I try Binding to the properties I can't. I've tried Binding Record.Name, Binding record.Name, Binding FieldsProto.etc... Nothing seems to work. I know I'm probably doing this completely wrong but I can't find any docs on nested property binding when it comes to binding to the response of a RESTful web service. Please help!!

Kind regards,
Aspiring Apollo

[image]

Comment: each item in your CollectionView is a `BusinessItem`, so you need too bind to properties of that class.  ie, "{Binding _fieldsProto.name.stringValue}".

Comment: @Jason I tried that and got the following - "Projects/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/Views/SearchPage.xaml(32,32): Error XFC0045: Binding: Property "_fieldsProto" not found on "xxxxxx.Models.BusinessReturnedModel". (XFC0045) (xxxxxx) XamlC"

Comment: this is not correct `x:DataType="businessReturned:BusinessReturnedModel"`

Comment: @Jason what should it be based on the model above?

Comment: read my first comment

Comment: @Jason like this?...
x:DataType="businessReturned:BusinessReturnedModel.BusinessItem">

Comment: I don't know.  I generally don't use the DataType property, you will have to try and see if it works

Comment: @Jason I just can't seem to bind to the properties of the BusinessItem. It's driving me mental. Thanks for having an attempt at it Jason, I appreciate it anyway.

Comment: I would get rid of DataType and just enter the binding expression I suggested

Comment: @Jason I did that and this is the error: Projects/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/Views/SearchPage.xaml(32,32): Error XFC0045: Binding: Property "_fieldsProto" not found on "xxxxxx.ViewModels.SearchViewModel". (XFC0045) (xxxxxx) XamlC

Comment: there is no "SearchViewModel" in **any** of the code you posted.  Try `{Binding .}` to see if it will print the name of the class it thinks it is bound to

Comment: @Jason the SearchViewModel is the view model posted above, I forgot to include the name of the VM.

Comment: @Jason I tried the above but unfortunately didn't get an output

Comment: if you can post the code somewhere I'll take a quick look at it.  What you're describing is really odd